# Dependent Object Creation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

**Environment:**

I am working in Webapi. There is 2 entity classes which are follows;

```
public class Class1
{
    public Class1()
    {
        this.items = new HashSet<Class2>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Class2> items { get; set; }
}

public class Class2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Class1Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Class1 class1 { get; set; }
}
```

**Business Layer:**
The buniess layer have the following codes;

```
public class Class1Logic : IClass1Logic
{
    private readonly IClass1Repository _repo;
    public Class1Logic(IClass1Repository repository)
    {
        _repo = repository;
    }

    public async Task<bool> AddClass1ItemAsync(Class1 item)
    {
        _repo.Add(item);
        bool status = await _repo.SaveAsync();
        return status;
    }

    public async Task<Class1> GetClass1ItemAsync(int id)
    {
        return await _repo.GetAsync(id);
    }
}

public class Class2Logic : IClass1Logic
{
    private readonly IClass2Repository _repo;
    public Class2Logic(IClass2Repository repository)
    {
        _repo = repository;
    }

    public async Task<bool> AddClass2ItemAsync(Class2 item)
    {
        _repo.Add(item);
        bool status = await _repo.SaveAsync();
        return status;
    }

    public async Task<Class2> GetClass2ItemAsync(int id)
    {
        return await _repo.GetAsync(id);
    }
}
```

**ViewModels:**

```
public class Class1Model
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Class2Model
{
    public int Id { get; internal set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Class1Id { get; set; }
    public string Class1Name { get; internal set; }
}
```

**Controllers:**

There are 2 contrtollers like Class1Controller and Class2Controller. Both have all CRUD operations.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/class1items")]
public class Class1Controller : ApiController
{
    private readonly IClass1Logic _class1Logic;
    private ModelFactory TheFactory;
    public Class1Controller(IClass1Logic class1Logic)
    {
        _class1Logic = class1Logic;
        TheFactory = new ModelFactory();
    }

    [Route("")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(Class1Model class1Model)
    {
        var item = TheFactory.Parse(class1Model);
        bool result = await _class1Logic.AddClassItemAsync(item);
        if (!result)
        {
            return BadRequest("Error");
        }
        string uri = Url.Link("GetLabById", new { id = item.Id });
        return Created(uri, TheFactory.Create(item));
    }

    [Route("{id:int}", Name = "GetClass1ItemById")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetClass1Item(int id)
    {
        Class1 item = await _class1Logic.GetClassItemAsync(id);
        if (item == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return Ok(TheFactory.Create(item));
    }

}

[RoutePrefix("api/class2items")]
public class Class2Controller : ApiController
{
        private readonly IClass2Logic _class2Logic;
        private ModelFactory TheFactory;
        public Class2Controller(IClass2Logic class2Logic)
        {
            _class2Logic = class2Logic;
            TheFactory = new ModelFactory();
        }

        [Route("")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(Class2Model class2Model)
        {
            var item = TheFactory.Parse(class2Model);
        ***//Here item should include Class1 object even if user give ClassId in class2Model***

        bool result = await _class2Logic.AddClassItemAsync(item);
            if (!result)
            {
                return BadRequest("Error");
            }
            string uri = Url.Link("GetClass2ItemById", new { id = item.Id });
            return Created(uri, TheFactory.Create(item));
        }

    }
```

There is not dependecies in Class1. So all operations are fine. In Class2Controller post method, I got the model object as following to create Class2.

```
{
  "id": 0,
  "name": "string",
  "class1Id": 1
}
```

**Understanding:**

I need to return this viewmodel to user after the create the record. The record created successfully but when mapping to viewmodel i got null exception as Class1 object not in the Class2 object.

In order to get the Class2 object including class1 object, I need to give the class1Object in the request object.

For this i need to find the Class1 object with Class1Id in the request object.

**ViewMapper Code:**

```
public class ModelFactory
{
    public Class1Model Create(Class1 item)
    {
        return new Class1Model
        {
            Id = item.Id,
            Name = item.Name
        };
    }
    public Class2Model Create(Class2 item)
    {
        return new Class2Model
        {
            Id = item.Id,
            Name = item.Name,
            Class1Id = item.class1.Id,
            Class1Name = item.class1.Name
        };
    }
    public  Class1 Parse(Class1Model modelItem)
    {
        return new Class1
        {
            Id = modelItem.Id,
            Name = modelItem.Name
        };
    }
    public Class2 Parse(Class2Model modelItem)
    {
        return new Class2
        {
            Id = modelItem.Id,
            Name = modelItem.Name,
            Class1Id = modelItem.Class1Id,
            ***/*Issue Place*/
            //class1 =  Need to set property by getting object using modelItem.Class1Id***      
        };
    }
}
```

**Issue:**

Now i need to call get method of Class1Controller by passing Class1Id.

How to call and is this correct? or my design is bad?

This is initial case. If my Class3 have both Class1 and Class2 again i need to call methods of Class1 and Class2.

Please help to find the correct solution in this case

*Note: I added comments the issue area to understand*

Comment: that's a wrong kind of class design.  look carefully and you will find *circular reference*

Comment: @Rahul yes. Actually i created viewmodel to and from client. I added viewmodel. When parse to business entity i need to updated the Class1 object. Please suggest your way

Comment: Please post code that doing save and mapping from viewmodel (where you got null exception). `Now i need to call get method of Class1Controller by passing Class1Id.` - you need to do this work in data or business layer, don't use Controller methods for this kind of work

Comment: @DenisKrasakov  fine. I added the full code excluding repository layer. I commented the issue area in controller and mapper class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, just to fix this issue you need to manually call `_class1Logic.GetClass1ItemAsync` after saving. However this doesn't look good.

More elegant ways to fix it:

1) If you always need `Class2.Class1` field to be filled use `Include` when you fetch data (in repository): `dbContext.Set<Class2>().Include(c => c.class1)`.

2) Also you can turn on LazyLoading for EF - I assume it should work in your case.

3) Inject class1Repo to class2Logic and fix up class1 reference after saving - in case if you don't want to enable lazy loading or item was detached from context after save method

Thoughts about design:

I suggest you to look at [Automapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started) or simular libraries instead of `ModelFactory` where you going to have all mapping logic

**Edit:** About generic repository: you can modify you `GetAsync` method

```
public async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(int id, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
    where T: class, IEntity
{
    var query = context.Set<T>().AsQueryable();

    if (includes.Length > 0)
    {
        query = includes.Aggregate(query,
          (current, include) => current.Include(include));
    }

    return await query.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);
}
```

IEntity interface:

```
interface IEntity
{
    int Id { get; }
}
```

With this implementation you can use

```
await _repo.GetAsync<Class2>(id, x => x.class1);
```

Comment: thanks. ModelFactory is just for checkout. Surly i will use AutoMapper.

Comment: thanks. 1)But the situation is happened in add method only due to detached. You mean to use Include() when adding. But my repository is generic repository. So i need to find all navigation properties and include that. This is not good 2) Lazy Loading already enabled and the issue in add method only. 3)Yes instead of aftersave, i just add the internal object in add method of business. Here my confusion is further if any object needs multiple internal object all repo needs to inject..

Comment: great!!! I like this way and solved my problem. Exactly it fits in my repository.